# How to count different values of a column of a dataframe and sort into a new dataframe? Seperated by every few rows of said dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of pitches thrown and would like to count each number of balls and strikes of each plate appearance. The dataframe contains pitches by game and by plate appearance  of each game and by the number of the pitch within each plate appearance but is not separated into separate plate appearances. I would like to create a new dataframe which lists each plate appearance with the number of balls and strikes thrown.

I've tried some loops but have not had success in separating the data and storing it into a new dataframe. I've only been able to print the results of each plate appearance. I separated each game into dataframes for each game but assume there is a way to do this without creating subsets for each game.

Team.pitchlog is a dataframe with columns of Game ID indicating which game the pitch is from and AB # which indicates the plate appearance number (yes AB instead of PA was an error but since all the dataframes use this I have not changed the column headers yet) and each row is its own pitch thrown with a Result column indicating whether the pitch was a ball or strike.

Team.gm1=subset(Team.pitchlog, Team.pitchlog$`Game ID`==1)

for (i in 1:39) {
    print (count(Team.gm1$Result[Team.gm1$`AB #`==i]))
}

I expect a dataframe with each row being a plate appearance and columns of Game ID, Plate Appearance ID, and columns for balls and strikes.

Comment: `count` expects a data.frame and not a vector as input.  You may need `for(i in 1:39) print(table(Team.gm1$Result[Team.gm1$AB #==i]))`

Comment: you may want to add some reproducible example to get quick help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  `filter` the rows where 'Game ID' is 1, then split the dataset into a `list` of dataset based on the value of 'AB #' and get the frequency of 'Result' by looping over the `list` with `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
Team.pitchlog %>%
       filter(`Game ID` == 1) %>%
       select(`AB #`, Result) %>%
       mutate(Result = factor(Result)) %>%
       group_split(`AB #`) %>%
       map(~ .x %>%
                count(Result, .drop = FALSE))
```

---

In the OP's post, `count` (from `dplyr`) is applied on a `vector` as input while the help page of `?count` gives specifies the input 'x' as

> x - a tbl() to tally/count.

If we wanted to use the same syntax, an option is `table` from `base R` which can take a vector

```
for (i in 1:39) print (table(Team.gm1$Result[Team.gm1$`AB #`==i]))
```

Comment: That was extremely helpful, my only qualm is, and I did not realize this when describing my issue, I need zero counts to be included and as far as I know the count function does not include zero counts. Any way around this?

Comment: @AlexDaSilva  Do you meant to say that if the element in absent, it is not included?

Comment: @AlexDaSilva  If the column is `factor`, then you can use  `count(Result, .drop = FALSE))`  As a reproducible example `df1 <- data.frame(col = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 20, replace = TRUE));df1 %>% count(col = factor(col, levels =LETTERS[1:5]), .drop = FALSE)`

Comment: I want the zero counts to be included, that being if the count of strikes for example is zero, I would like it to be shown in the list as a zero, rather than excluding the zero.

Comment: Gm.1=Team.pitchlog %>% 
  filter(`Game ID` == 1) %>%
  select(`AB #`, Result) %>%
  group_split(`AB #`) %>% 
  map(~ .x %>% 
        count(Result, .drop = FALSE)) #I tried this but to no avail.

Comment: @AlexDaSilva  Please check my previous comment

Comment: @AlexDaSilva  AFter the `select` step, add `mutate(Result = factor(Result)) %>%`  I think this should work